# update time and create time of tables is showing null in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

The columns update_time and create_time is having the value NULL in the information_schema Tables of MYSQL. How can the value be NULL?. Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

For memory tables this is normal behavior.

With InnoDB tables, this is a known bug and have been for years. See

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14374

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69689

Comment: hi Janne thanks for the reply, almost 80% of the tables have these column as null values... but the recently added ones have the timestamp value. can you explain me this also????

Comment: Are those MyISAM tables?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue and I'm trying to get to the bottom. Recently used tables do have `UPDATE_TIME` populated correctly despite being `InnoDB`. Any thoughts on how I can get the older tables using the `InnoDB` engine to also populate the `UPDATE_TIME`?